# MySQL and lock a table, read, and then truncate

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using mysqldb in python.

I need to do the following for a table.

```
1) Lock
2) Read
3) Truncate the table
4) Unlock
```

When I run the below code, I get the below error.  So, I am rather unsure on how to lock a table for reading it, then truncating the table.  I need to be sure that no other connection reads the data.

```
asin_list = [] 
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=parms['database']['operations']['host'],user=parms['database']['operations']['username'],passwd=parms['database']['operations']['password'],db=parms['database']['operations']['database'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = "LOCK TABLES asin_one_time_only READ"
    cursor.execute(query)
    print 'fu1'

    query = """select asin FROM asin_one_time_only""" 
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        asin_list.append(row[0]) 

    print asin_list
    print 'fu2'
    query = "UNLOCK TABLES;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()


    print 'fu3'
    query = "LOCK TABLES asin_one_time_only WRITE"
    cursor.execute(query)


    query = """truncate table amz_one_time_only""" 
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

    print 'fu3'
    query = "UNLOCK TABLES;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close() 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Amazon-Products-Crawler-1/threaded_crawl.py", line 1086, in <module>
    onetime = getOneTimeOnlyAsins(parms)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Amazon-Products-Crawler-1/threaded_crawl.py", line 109, in getOneTimeOnlyAsins
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1192, "Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't truncate a table that is locked for writing. This is because "truncate" means "destroy the table, and recreate a new one with the same schema."

You can however, *empty* the table. Instead of `TRUNCATE TABLE asin_one_time_only` use `DELETE FROM asin_one_time_only`. Note that this will not reset the autoincrement numbering. If you want to reset it as well, use `ALTER TABLE asin_one_time_only auto_increment=1`

I suggest doing this:

```sql
LOCK TABLES asin_one_time_only READ;
SELECT asin FROM asin_one_time_only;
-- minimize the possibility of someone writing to the table in-between
-- an "UNLOCK TABLES" and a "LOCK TABLES" by just issuing a new LOCK TABLES
-- I am not 100% sure that MySQL will do this atomically, so there is a
-- possibility that you may delete a row that was not read.
-- If this is unacceptable, then use a "LOCK TABLES asin_one_time_only WRITE"
-- from the very beginning.
LOCK TABLES asin_one_time_only WRITE;
DELETE FROM asin_one_time_only;
ALTER TABLE asin_one_time_only auto_increment=1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I this error is I delete FROM table rather than trncate.  amz_one_time_only' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

Comment: Is your table `amz_one_time_only` or `asin_one_time_only`?

Comment: This just helped save a load of time rewriting some stored procedures :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't truncate a table that's locked for writing.

There's a whole debate on the issue here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20667

What you can do, however is drop the table and re-create it.

Comment: If you drop the table, the lock will be released. This means that other clients that are reading/writing the table in the instant between dropping the table and recreating it will get "table does not exist" errors instead of blocking. If this is unacceptable, then you need to empty the table, not drop it.