# MySql:what is the result when executes insert or update in truncate process, the two operations are in two connections

Tags: mysql, insert, truncate

I want to truncate a table when there is no insert or update operations on the table, but if the truncate operation is very slow ,maybe insert operation will be executed ,so what will be happend in this case;

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921366/mysql-and-lock-a-table-read-and-then-truncate

Comment: First, truncate is pretty fast.  Second, I'm pretty sure that it locks the table so no inserts take place during the truncate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In between the end of truncate and the recreation of the new table, anyone reading would get a table does not exist error.  But in the link I gave above, one workaround is to delete all records with a table lock.  Then no one would ever see this happening.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you . yeah,usually the operation is very fast, the truncate operation is designed to delete large data with less system resource ,I don't know whether you test it with large data or not , but others also have questions about slow truncate in large data case. thanks again

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, I will try the workaround,it seems good.